# Does Sencha Touch 2.4 have iOS 8.1/8 themes?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I checked the Kitchen Sink example and it seems that there is no new theme for iOS 8.1/8.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that iOS 8 is way identical to iOS 7 in applications UI design. It includes several minor UI tweaks which don't belong to any application themselves, but global stuffs (multitasking screen or searching screen for example).

So I think there isn't a necessity to create a dedicated theme for iOS 8.